# Format to view on iOS and PS3?

Tags: file-formats, ios

I have Apple Compressor and have been trying to determine the correct format for my videos to allow them to play on both the iPad and my PlayStation 3 via a Media Server. Can anyone help me to determine a format that both can play? I'd hate to have to keep two copies of the same video on my Media Server. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MP4 with AAC audio and h.264 video is *definitely* playable on the PS3, and since it's an extension of Apple's .mov files, it should work on all the iDevices too.

For maximum compatibility, use the h.264 'baseline' profile, and avoid AAC-HE.

Older devices (like some DVD players) may require XVID video and AC3 audio in an AVI container, but that won't apply to either the PS3 or iPad.

Comment: Thanks, there's a lot to try to wade through on formats. I appreciate the help!